# change " password reset " url link

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to create a different url link for laravel password reset.
by default that link is :

`mysite/html/password/reset/74d9f53e5b8166ba0544122d1dc4451a76f707f4`

whereas, i want to be this :

`mysite/html/auth/resetpassword/74d9f53e5b8166ba0544122d1dc4451a76f707f4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the **URI**. Use something like `URL::to('auth/resetpassword/'.$token);`

Comment: i want to change link that will send to the user email. where should i write this?

Comment: At the password reminder view file. Check your views folder for a file responsible for that

Comment: @Richie In which directory it is in. I am using laravel 5, I am not getting this file.

Comment: @Mukesh In the `views` folder

Comment: Hm... Can't find on laravel 5.8